Convex hull of a set of points in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$
The problem is the following. Let us consider the set of points $(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $x_{1}=0$ or $x_{1}=1$ and for $k>1$, $x_{k+1}=0$ or $x_{k+1}=x_{k}+1$
For example:
$$L_{2}:=\left\{ (0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,2) \right\}$$
$$L_{3}:=\left\{ (0, 0, 0),(0, 0, 1),(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 0),(1, 0, 1),(1, \
2, 0),(1, 2, 3) \right\}$$
And let us consider its convex hull $C(L_{n})$. Then graphically and computationally I have as a hypothesis that
$$C(L_{n})=\left\{ (x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})\in \mathbb{R}^{n}:0\le x_{1}\le 1 \wedge 0\le x_{k+1}\le x_{k}+1 \ \text{for} \ k>1 \right\}$$
How can I prove this? Honestly, I've rarely worked with convex hulls and I can't think of a way to prove it. I apologize in advance if this is a very silly question.

what is $0 \wedge 0$?

@vallev It is actually the logical 'AND' of two inequalities

I change your condition, I believe you mean $0\le x_1\le 1$. Also can you prove that all the points of $L_n$ are the vertices of the convex hull?

In fact all the points of $L_{n}$ are the vertices of the convex hull, however as I mentioned I don't see how to use this to prove what I'm asking : (

I think this problem is true. As I'm going to sleep now, I am just write some hint here, if there is no answer, I will write an answer. So you have a region that is consists of $2n$ linear inequalities. First  all your vertices satisfies these inequalities. And because of the half spaces' intersection is convex, the region will mention is a convex region and contains the convex hull. Then prove every point in the region is a convex combination of some points in $L_n$, By induction, entry-wise from the last to the first.

p.s. I think proving those are vertices of convex hull has the same difficulty with proving the convex hull is the region you mentioned.

You can also use the definition of convex combinations to directly show that your set is closed under convex combinations. Because it also contains all points in $L_n$
, we then get that its a superset. Then you can, in this case, show that the corners of your set are exactly the points of $L_n$
, and therefore that your set is exactly $C(L_n)$
. For the latter notice that a point is an corner if and only if for any direction you can't move in both ways for along the direction without falling out of the set. And that's exactly those points for which the inequalities are strict

The dimension is $n$. Vertices must satisfy at least $n$ inequalities at equality.

The answer is yes. First, we know that $C(L_n)$ is a convex region (it is an intersection of several half-spaces, thus convex.) and all the points in $L_n$ are in $C(L_n)$. So the convex hull of $L_n$ is included in $C(L_n)$. Now, we prove that all the points in $C(L_n)$ can be written as a convex combination of points in $L_n$. We use induction.
For $n=1$ it is trivial. Let $n-1$ case
$$C(L_{n-1})=\left\{ (x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n-1})\in \mathbb{R}^{n}:0\le x_{1}\le 1 \wedge 0\le x_{k+1}\le x_{k}+1 \ \text{for} \ k>1 \right\}$$
is the convex hull of $L_{n-1}$. Let $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be a point in $C(L_n)$, and thus $(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$ is a point in $C(L_{n-1})$. By induction, we can write $(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$ as a convex combination of points in $L_{n-1}$: for each point $p_k=(X_1^{(k)},\dots,X_{n-1}^{(k)})$ in $L_{n-1}$, its coefficient is $\lambda_k$.
Consider $L_n$, it consist two types of points, one are points in $C_{n-1}$ and the last coefficient is zero, we call them $q_k=(X_1^{(k)},\dots,X_{n-1}^{(k)},0)$. And, one is points in $C_{n-1}$ and the last coefficient is $n-1$th coordinate plus one, we call them $r_k=(X_1^{(k)},\dots,X_{n-1}^{(k)},X_{n-1}^{(k)}+1)$. Consider the conbination
$$\sum_{k}\frac{x_n}{1+x_{n-1}}\lambda_k r_k+\frac{1+x_{n-1}-x_n}{1+x_{n-1}}\lambda_k q_k$$
This is a convex combination of points in $L_n$. By induction, we have $\sum_{k}\lambda_k q_k=(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},0)$ and $\sum_{k}\lambda_k r_k=(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},x_{n-1}+1)$ (since the last coordinate is $\sum_{k}\lambda_k(X_{n-1}^{(k)}+1)=\sum_{k}\lambda_kX_{n-1}^{(k)}+\sum_{k}\lambda_k=x_{n-1}+1$.) Thus, the combination is
$$\frac{x_n}{1+x_{n-1}}(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},x_{n-1}+1)+\frac{1+x_{n-1}-x_n}{1+x_{n-1}}(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},0)=(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n.)$$

Thank you very much! It's a very cool test : )
